# JS : pipelining chess game rules

Tags: javascript, pipeline, chess

[since my question was previously too long I reformulate it]

The question is about writing a pipeline to evaluate/apply a chess move and to produce moves from given position and flags.

INTRO:

In my fistory, I store the GameState as following :

```
GameState ::= [aggregate]
  + position (Map ref to chessman)
  + flags (object ket/values)
  + box (where to store captured chessmen)
  + move (which move produced this GameState, null at initialization time)
```

With the positions Map :: ref -> chessman, I am able to compute a 'raycaster', a data structure tp store rays emitted by chessmen, and compute interactions (touches) between them. Touches can be crossings of rays and shadowing, when a chessman placed on board obfuscates paths of rays produced by other chessmen.

(the Raycaster is coded and works fine)

RULES PIPELINING:

Rules are expressed indicidually in separrate classes (one per rule), for example: PawnSimpleMove, PawnFirstMove, PawnCapture, DeltaMove (for ordinary chessman, not pawns), Check, endGame and so forth.

A RuleSet object stores a pipeline of rules (array) and call them sequentially

each rule has an "evaluate" method, with the following behavior :

- if it can apply: alter test gamestate (board and flags) and returnd TRUE
- if it doesn't apply: do not alter game state, and return FALSE
- if it is violated, throw an Error to notify the RuleSet to reject the candidate move

Each rule hqve a "generate" method which can produce an array of moves to be validated with "evaluate" of the whole pipeline

further more, the "evaluate"  of EndGame rule, neds to recall the "generate" of the pipeline to know about possible game duration (if not end game sets the END_GAME flag to true)

When the whole pipeline is validated (almost one true-ish rule result), the candidate move is accepted, and a new GameState { board, flags, move, box } can be inserted onto the history

THE QUESTION:

I think pipeline in RuleSet have to carry a context and pass it from a rule to another;

==> how to structure the RuleSet class and its pipeline ?

code samples (under cosntruction) are located at : https://github.com/hefeust/colorchess-v2

Any suggestions ?

EDIT: each stage has a set of methods a) evaluate and b) generate which are called serially. So I carrry a context along stages...

don't worry about raw performance I'm working on a kind of metrics to establish bounds to an AI evaluation/generation function,... doing pseudo empty moves, I can obtain two virtual situations, one is the best option and the second the worst.

```
// call serially methodA, methodB and methodC
class Stage {
  constructor() {

  }

  // pieline methods
  methodA(context) {}
  methodB(context) {}
  methodC(context) {}

}
```

Builfing a chess rules pipeline is for brinnging simplicity, ease of ynderstand,  and avoid spaghetti-like data and code.

Comment: Use bitboards? Every good chess AI uses bitboards to maintain game state, generates moves, etc.

Comment: hmm, in fact, I'm not properly coding a chess AI, rather a game helper... so performance doesn't matter essentilally now. If I would code an AI, I prefer to base it on heuristics, less performant, of course, but more natural, human friendly, than bruite force alpha-beta pruning on a big-big-big search tree !

Comment: Why is this tagged javascript?

Comment: my actual implementation is ES2015 + VueJS : but, yes, it 's a more generic question

Comment: In my youtube channel, I do this in Java.  It might apply to your JS approach.  You're welcome to go to my profile for a link to the series and github account.  I can't give you an answer in a paragraph or less.